# How to order a dictionary of dictionaries based on inner dictionary's value

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python which has dictionary values like this:

```
{'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5': 5.2}, 
 'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7': 3.9 , 'd8': 4.1},
 'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}
```

I want to rank this dictionary and show `d` variables based on decreasing value of the float 
values associated to them.

The results should be like this:

```
['d5', 'd8', 'd7', 'd4', 'd1', 'd3']
```

this is the part of the code that I wrote to fill my dictionary:

```
if q not in result.keys():
    result[q] = {id:rsv[id]}
elif id not in result[q]:
    result[q][id]=rsv[id]
```

I want to show id s which are sorted by rsv values.
Is there any way to do that? Or is there any alternative solution for ranking a dictionary based on a series of values?

Comment: Now you have more than one key in the nested dict. **What key** should those dictionaries be sorted on? What key is to be returned?

Comment: Are you trying to treat all nested dictionaries as one?

Comment: I've updated your post based on your comments on one of the answers (since deleted). This kind of information needs to be part of your question, not hidden in comments.

Comment: I want to sort and show the keys of the first dict based on the values of the second dictionary! Maybe this approach is wrong. The whole idea is to sort a dictionary based on some values. I'm also open to any solutions other than dict of dicts.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to display the outer dict keys q1, q2 and q3 in order based on the values of the inner dicts? How should an inner dict with more than one key-value pair be evaluated for sorting?

Comment: @Paper: yet you stated you wanted the `d` keys as output. Even if you wanted `q` keys instead, by what criteria are they sorted?

Comment: no I want to show the keys of the inner dictionary which is sorted base on the values of it

Comment: I'm trying to rank a dictionary based on some values. I would also appreciate any alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aim for code clarity, and think it is best achieved with a little more lines in this case. Please note that the indentation used is to better show the structure.

This answer contains intermediate results that are often needed, in my experience. It preserves them as dictionaries until the end where only keys are needed.

First, the Python 2.x version just because:

```
d = {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5': 5.2},
     'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7': 3.9 , 'd8': 4.1},
     'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}

# First, flatten to a list of one key-value pair dictionaries
inner_dicts = [
    dict([(k,v)]) 
    for inner_d in d.values() 
        for (k, v) in inner_d.items()]

# Second, sort that list based on the value in each dict
dictlist_sorted = sorted(
    inner_dicts, 
    key=lambda temp_d: temp_d.values()[0], 
    reverse=True)

# Third, extract the key of each dict
keys_sorted = [temp_d.keys()[0] for temp_d in dictlist_sorted]

print keys_sorted
```

Second, the Python 3 version:

```
d = {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5': 5.2},
     'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7': 3.9 , 'd8': 4.1},
     'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}

# First, flatten to a list of one key-value pair dictionaries
inner_dicts = [
    dict([(k,v)]) 
    for inner_d in d.values() 
        for (k, v) in inner_d.items()]

# Second, sort that list based on the value in each dict
dictlist_sorted = sorted(
    inner_dicts, 
    key=lambda temp_d: list(temp_d.values())[0], 
    reverse=True)

# Third, extract the key of each dict
keys_sorted = [list(temp_d.keys())[0] for temp_d in dictlist_sorted]

print(keys_sorted)
```

Comment: the inner dicts will have more than one key-value pair each. is it possible to sort this kind of dict?

Comment: @Papar, I updated my answer (even though you already have accepted another answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since the op changed the spec to have multiple key-value pairs in inner dicts, I thought I'd show off a solution that draws on some of the ideas from @jarno-lamberg. The key here is that since it seems like the outer mapping is irrelevant, I first grab all of the dicts and flatten them into a list of tuples.

```
d =  {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5': 5.2}, 
      'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7': 3.9 , 'd8': 4.1},
      'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}
d_flattened = [(k,v) for temp_d in d.values() for k,v in temp_d.items()]
d_sorted = sorted(d_flattened, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
print(', '.join(k for k,v in d_sorted))
```

Comment: @Papar: note that this is *exactly* what my solution accomplishes.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the values, extracted to tuples of value and key (in that order), and afterwards extract the key:

```
[key for value, key in sorted(
    (item[::-1] for d in outer.values() for item in d.items()), 
    reverse=True)]
```

The `(item[::-1] for d in outer.values() for item in d.items())` expression extracts the `(key, value)` pairs from each nested dictionary value, reversing the key and value for easy sorting.

The sorting then takes the first values, reversed, after which the outer list comprehension extracts just the keys again.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5':5.2}, 'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7':3.9 , 'd8':4.1}, 'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}
>>> outer = {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5':5.2}, 'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7':3.9 , 'd8':4.1}, 'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}
>>> sorted((item[::-1] for d in outer.values() for item in d.items()), reverse=True)
[(5.2, 'd5'), (4.1, 'd8'), (3.9, 'd7'), (3.23, 'd4'), (1.2, 'd1'), (0.5, 'd3')]
>>> [key for value, key in sorted(
...     (item[::-1] for d in outer.values() for item in d.items()), 
...     reverse=True)]
['d5', 'd8', 'd7', 'd4', 'd1', 'd3']
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: Yes, BTW the name of my dictionary is result and this is the code that I tried: [key for value, key in sorted((result[q].items()[0][::-1] for result[q] in result.values()))]

Comment: @Papar: replace `outer` in my code with `result`. Nothing more, or do `outer = result` first.

Comment: It just returns one value and this value also is not supposed to be the first one in the list. I should mention that the inner dictionary is not like a tuple and can have more than one key like this: {'q1': {'d1': 1.2 , 'd5':5.2}, 'q2': {'d4': 3.23, 'd7':3.9 , 'd8':4.1}, 'q3': {'d3': 0.5}}

Comment: @Papar: then *update your question* with that information. What key and would be chosen in that case? I cannot answer without an accurate problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in two steps: sort, then display. For sorting, use a key function:

```
d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: list(x[1].values())[0])
```

Then, display the data:

```
print(', '.join(list(x[1].keys())[0] for x in d_sorted))
```

In general this is a good idea because you might want to reuse the sorted data in full.

Comment: The OP is using Python 3, so `.keys()[0]` is going to fail here.

Comment: @martijn-pieters Right you are. Fixed.

Comment: Except that the print call is missing parentheses.